# Add source computers public IP to email header with unix mail OS X

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, ip, postfix-mta

For security purposes we want to include the source computers public IP address in the header of any e-mails sent. I can easily find it and pop it in the body of the e-mail, but we sort of want some evidence that the e-mail itself originated from the same IP address.

I'm sending some system information via `postfix` mail command in terminal in OS X and at the moment I'm using `Turbo SMTP` as the SMTP server to do it.

Is there a way for me to do it from terminal or is it all down to the SMTP server if that data is sent in the header?

If so, might it be better to run my own SMTP server on a linux server which does send the public IP?

At the moment the header just includes the SMTP servers IP and my receiving e-mail servers IP.

Comment: Why wouldn't it originate from the same IP address? Because someone used a VPN? Because in that case, you're out of luck

Comment: Nope - i'm testing on my computer, no VPN, its a totally open public IP, but all the header is showing is the receiving SMTP and my receiving servers IP.